# How can I use a macro from another Maven module?

Tags: maven, freemarker, magnolia

I have a Magnolia instance with two Maven modules - **A** & **B**.

In module **A** I have a file with a macro - *macro.ftl*.

In module **B** I have a template file - *template.ftl*.

And what I want to do in *template.ftl* is to import the macro.

`[#import "path/to/the/macro.ftl" as macro]`

However I have no idea how. And the worst part is - I don't even know what it is that I don't know.

Comment: I don't know Magnolia, only FreeMarker. But it might helps in searching for solution that this depends on what `TemplateLoader`-s Magnolia configures for FreeMarker. Like there's `ClassTemplateLoader`, which can load templates that the Java class loader can load (like resources in Maven dependencies). And there's `MultiTemplateLoader` which looks for templates in multiple `TemplateLoader`-s.

Answer (score 0):

```
[#include ""path/to/the/macro.ftl"]
```

Try this. You should be able to use macro in any of the FTL file